# What is the Hexagon design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I've been watching this https://plus.google.com/events/ci2g23mk0lh9too9bgbp3rbut0k

they mention a term I am not familiar with

What is the Hexagon design pattern ?

Comment: It's mentioned just after [2:48](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9quxZsLcfo#t=168) in the context of Mock-heavy TDD environments.

Comment: Good video on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDWApqAUjEI

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture and 
https://github.com/jschairb/sandbox/wiki/HexagonalArchitecture

> Hexagonal Architecture is an architecture defined by establishing a
>   perimeter around the domain of your application and establishing
>   adapters for input/output interactions. By establishing this isolation
>   layer, the application becomes unaware of the nature of the things
>   it's interacting with.
>
> Create your application to work without either a UI or a database so
>   you can run automated regression-tests against the application, work
>   when the database becomes unavailable, and link applications together
>   without any user involvement. - Alistair Cockburn

Comment: Huh. I figured it would have something to do with hexagons. Goes to show that [naming things is the hardest part of programming](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html), I suppose.

Comment: The diagrams on the linked pages indeed have 6 sides, but there's no reason for them to have 6 sides other than the fact they were drawn that way. The docs talk about establishing ports and interfaces, and the diagrams show each port/interface occupying a face of the enclosing polygon. However, the most involved diagram only shows four used faces. It could have been named "Pentagonal architecture" or "Heptagonal architecture" and the only observed change would be more people questioning why the number was important.

Comment: "The hexagon is not a hexagon because the number six is important, but rather to allow the people doing the drawing to have room to insert ports and adapters as they need, not being constrained by a one-dimensional layered drawing."

Comment: All the site content seems to have gone. Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170606075805/http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture

Answer (score 11):

Are you refering to Hexagonal design pattern?

Intent of Hexagonal design pattern

Allow an application to equally be driven by users, programs, automated test or batch scripts, and to be developed and tested in isolation from its eventual run-time devices and databases.

As events arrive from the outside world at a port, a technology-specific adapter converts it into a usable procedure call or message and passes it to the application. The application is blissfully ignorant of the nature of the input device. When the application has something to send out, it sends it out through a port to an adapter, which creates the appropriate signals needed by the receiving technology (human or automated). The application has a semantically sound interaction with the adapters on all sides of it, without actually knowing the nature of the things on the other side of the adapters.

[Read more about it at here](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture)

Backup version of the article here : https://staging.cockburn.us/hexagonal-architecture/

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding its a bit of a buzz-word for the general software engineering practice of separation-of-concerns. It basically states that your i/o logic should be hidden from your domain logic. So you core business logic can be adapted to different "users". Its very closely related to the MVC pattern.

I think the "Hexagonal Architecture" name has just be made up by the presentor. And some people are picking it up.

Comment: Every single software design pattern or guideline or whatnut is some form of "general software engineering practice of separation-of-concerns" :-)

Comment: This is not much of an Answer. Stack Overflow is *not* a casual discussion board for tossing around conjecture. If you do not have specific technical knowledge on the point, refrain from posting here.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like an overall system design. You basically want your code to be equally friendly to all comers.

To support that, for example, webservices conform to standards and generally, universally, support JSON. Why? Webclients come in all forms so following standards allows your clients to easily integrate. JSON takes it a step further: It makes dropping a UI on top painless.

From a technology perspective you can't totally build a future-proof service. Just make sure the objective of the service is clear/clean and true to purpose. If that purpose no longer suites then you need (a) new service(s)

This is easier said than done. When you start to get leaned on by your boss to compromise these principles for the sake of expediency you do what you must to get him/her off your back. But, the hack is done and generally the result is that the service takes on unrelated logic that it permanently ends up owning.

If you can drive one principle into your system design it's this:
*Open for extension. Closed for modification*